# Javascript on screen calculations from select / radio box

Tags: javascript, forms

Currently I am working on a reservations website, I have implemented select boxes and radio buttons to enable the user to select their party size and if they want VIP seating. I have also implemented a price factor based off of these two selections.

I have enabled php to perform the calculations once the submit button is pressed by the user, however I would much prefer for these calculations to be performed automatically on screen as well, using javascript, once the user makes a selection.

Here is the html code for the party size selection:

```
<select name="party" value="<?php echo $party;?>">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="5") echo "selected";?> value="5">1 Person (£5)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="10") echo "selected";?> value="10">2 People (£10)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="15") echo "selected";?> value="15">3 People (£15)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="20") echo "selected";?> value="20">4 People (£20)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="25") echo "selected";?> value="25">5 People (£25)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="30") echo "selected";?> value="30">6 People (£30)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="35") echo "selected";?> value="35">7 People (£35)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="40") echo "selected";?> value="40">8 People (£40)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="45") echo "selected";?> value="45">9 People (£45)</option>
<option <?php if (isset($party) && $party=="50") echo "selected";?> value="50">10+ People (£50)</option>
</select>
<span id="party" class="error"><?php echo $partyErr;?></span>
```

Here is the html code for the VIP selection:

```
<strong> VIP area* : </strong> <br><br>
Yes (+£5) <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="Yes") echo "checked";?> value="Yes">
<br><span id="vip" class="error"><?php echo $vipErr;?></span><br>
No <input type="radio" name="vip" <?php if (isset($vip) && $vip=="No") echo "checked";?> value="No">
```

Heres the line I wish to display the total price on:

```
<strong>Total booking cost based on party size & VIP selection: £<span id="price">0</span></strong>
```

Here is the javascript I have thus far:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on('change', '#party', function(e) {
         $('#price').html(parseInt($(this).val()) + parseInt($('input[name="vip"]').val()));
    });

     $(document).on('click', 'input[name="vip"]', function(e) {
         $('#price').html(parseInt($('#party').val()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

Currently the totals of each price aren't being calculated. When the user clicks a party size, the total cost shows blank and if the user selects to be seated in a VIP area, no change is made either. There is probably a simple error in my coding so if anyone knows how  I can fix this to make it function properly, please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are selecting the span element, not the select. To correct this, you can change the "on" statement as follows:

```
$("select[name=party]").on("change", function() {
    //your handler code
});
```

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new to js, could you please explain which line I should implement your suggestion? :(

Comment: Sure, just replace "$(document).on('change', '#party', function(e) {" with the "on" statement above. You also should remove the double quotes surrounding vip from $('input[name="vip"]'

Answer (score 0):

The selector you are using is wrong since "party" is the name of the select and not the ID.

```
$(document).on('change', '#party', function(e) {
```

Change your select element to

```
<select id="party" value="<?php echo $party;?>">
```

and change the id of your span below to something else.

Same thing applies to your VIP input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I applied the suggested changes however the total price still isnt calculated! Your changes also affected the selections from sticking once the user presses submit

Comment: I just noticed that you have another issue there. The result of $('input[name="vip"]').val() is always "Yes" because that is the value of the first radio element it gets. You have two radio elements with the same name so this will never work. I would suggest you to change that to a checkbox element or another select. I took the liberty to create a fiddle to better demonstrate what you need and to simplify your code. See if that is good for you http://fiddle.jshell.net/sohmfo1y/. Please also note that I removed the PHP code from that in order to work